# Возможны ли сочетания "длинные правила", "развернутые правила"?

Tags: семантика

Как правильно указать на большое, превосходящее обычное число правил настольной игры, если они занимают, например, несколько десятков страниц (30-40)? "Развернутые правила" не подходит, так как всякие правила, прилагаемые к настольным играм, являются развернутыми, полными. Сочетаний "Длинные правила" и "Обширные правила" не могу найти — можно ли выбрать один из этих оборотов? Обстоятельные — не могу выбрать по той же причине, что и "развернутые".

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос.

*Длинные правила* звучит смешно, если они так называются. Другое дело *длинный список правил*.
Но фраза ***какие же эти правила длинные*** вопросов не вызывает.
Но не: *У меня дома есть длинные правила игры.*
Но так нормально: *У меня дома есть длинный список правил игры.*

*Обширные правила* — нормально. Но да, это слово как-то не используется, так не говорят, хотя суть отображает хорошо.

Может, *подробные правила игры*? В них описаны мельчайшие подробности, и оттого они такие длинные.
Или можно *детальные правила игры*. Там расписаны все мельчайшие детали процесса игры.

О, а может, так? *Расширенные правила игры.*

*Развёрнутые правила* не означает непосредственно *полные* (это как следствие).
*Развёрнутые* — широкие, их широко развернули.

Comment: Если подробные и детальные, предполагается, что существуют неподробные правила, т. е. такие, которые не раскрывают всех возможных обстоятельств, которые могли бы возникнуть в игре — такие правила бессмысленны. Правила, подразумевается, и так всегда подробные. Я хочу найти слово, которое бы указало на объём текста, необходимого для изложения (подробного) всех правил, отличный от среднего объёма.

Comment: Может, *объёмные правила*?

Comment: А что насчёт *многостраничные правила*?

Comment: А если *большие правила*?

Comment: Для названия *длинные правила* смешно, а для указания на объём текста в самый раз. Например: *Какие же у этой игры длинные/большие правила.*

Comment: Да, эти варианты подходят

Comment: Отлично!.......

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сказал, что у этой игры чрезмерное количество правил.

Толковый словарь Ушакова:

> ЧРЕЗМЕ'РНЫЙ, ая, ое; -рен, рна, рно
> (книжн.). Превосходящий меру, слишком большой, слишком сильный. *Ч.
> наплыв посетителей. Чрезмерные расходы. Чрезмерные требования. Я
> страдала от чрезмерной признательности к нему. Чернышевский. Он
> чрезмерно (нареч.) скромен.*